# Folders under Cold Storage folder are Multi-Regional

Tags: synology

I am using Synology Hyper Backup to back up my NAS.  The bucket  is set to use Coldline and the root folder is indeed Coldline.  However, all of the folder are Multi-Regional. Is this an issue with the Synology software?  Is there a way I can force only Coldline?  Is there a way to change a folder from Multi-Region to Coldline after it has been created?

Thanks.

Comment: Same issue here, had a little bit of a surprise on my bill this month because of this. Have all the same questions.